# Meaning of Disallow: /*? in robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

[Yahoo's robots.txt](http://www.yahoo.com/robots.txt) contains:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /p/
Disallow: /r/
Disallow: /*?
```

What does the last line mean? ("Disallow: /*?")

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to web development, not to business it management.

Comment: @Daniel FYI At the time of posting the webmasters SE did not yet exist and we can't migrate questions older than 30 days...

Answer (score 5):

If it was a Perl regular expression:

```
*?     Match 0 or more times, not greedily
```

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

However `robots.txt` follows a really basic grammar, as such,

> To match a sequence of characters, use
>   an asterisk (*). For instance, to
>   block access to all subdirectories
>   that begin with private:
>
> ```
> User-agent: Googlebot
> Disallow: /private*/
> ```
>
> To block access to all URLs that
>   include a question mark (?) (more
>   specifically, any URL that begins with
>   your domain name, followed by any
>   string, followed by a question mark,
>   followed by any string):
>
> ```
> User-agent: Googlebot
> Disallow: /*?
> ```
>
> To specify matching the end of a URL,
>   use $. For instance, to block any URLs
>   that end with .xls:
>
> ```
> User-agent: Googlebot 
> Disallow: /*.xls$
> ```
>
> You can use this pattern matching in
>   combination with the Allow directive.
>   For instance, if a ? indicates a
>   session ID, you may want to exclude
>   all URLs that contain them to ensure
>   Googlebot doesn't crawl duplicate
>   pages. But URLs that end with a ? may
>   be the version of the page that you do
>   want included. For this situation, you
>   can set your robots.txt file as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> User-agent: *
> Allow: /*?$
> Disallow: /*?
> ```
>
> The Disallow: / *? directive will
>   block any URL that includes a ? (more
>   specifically, it will block any URL
>   that begins with your domain name,
>   followed by any string, followed by a
>   question mark, followed by any
>   string).
>
> The Allow: /*?$ directive will allow
>   any URL that ends in a ? (more
>   specifically, it will allow any URL
>   that begins with your domain name,
>   followed by a string, followed by a ?,
>   with no characters after the ?).

So basically any kind of query or search on Yahoo! is prohibited by a robot.

The expression support is confusingly not listed in the RFC, http://www.robotstxt.org/norobots-rfc.txt

The best description is provided by Google, http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449

Comment: so we dont get the link from yahoo

Comment: Every Yahoo! domain has a different robots.txt, check out Yahoo! from the homepage almost every link goes to a different domain with different restrictions.

Comment: It is very important to understand that many/most crawlers do not understand wildcards in robots.txt files, because that is not part of the specification.  According to http://robotstxt.org/, the only place where an asterisk is explicitly allowed is in the "User-agent" field.

Answer (score 0):

The * makes it a wildcard.  So, uri that ends with a ? would be restricted.

Comment: That would require "/*?$".